# Display Notification Bar on Header on Certain Post Count

Tags: posts, author, count

I want to display notification bar on header in my Wordpress theme when user submit certain number of post. I want to notify my author once they are submit amount of post. e.g.

if (authorpost === 50){

// congratulations! you have submitted total 50 posts bla bla.

} else if (authorpost === 100) {

// congratulations! you have submitted total 100 posts bla bla.

} else {
// nothing will display
}

I want this into header.php and will place my div right after  tag. Also I want to display only when they submit certain number of post as I mention above as soon as they cross that number it won't display anything.

Comment: Excuse me! I am trying to do in my wordpress template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way to achieve this would be to do something like the following;

```
<?php
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $post_count = count_user_posts($user_id);

    if ($post_count >= 50 && $post_count < 100) {
         // Congratulations you have submitted 50 posts!
    } elseif ($post_count >= 100) {
        // etc etc...
    } else {
        // do something else, or nothing.
    }
?>
```

You can place this within your header.php file, or for that matter in any template file should you choose to display this information elsewhere as this can run from out-side of your post loop.

WordPress API resources:

- `get_current_user_id` [LINK](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id)
- `count_user_posts` [LINK](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts)